# json_decode is failing when the json string contains \\b

Tags: php

I am trying to decode following JSON string using json_decode. The decode fails as the string contains `\b`.

```
$json = '{
    "question": {
    "content": "$(2,4)$ : 2x-y=2\\times \\blue2-\\pink4=0$ \n res"       
        }}' ;

$result = json_decode($json);  
print_r($result);
```

I am wondering what is the best way to decode ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, `\p` isn't a valid string escape sequence in JSON. That needs to be a double backslash. Which means you should have used a quadruple backslash for defining the JSON string in PHP context.

The backslash also escapes itself in single quoted strings. Use `print` to see what actual string you constructed before passing it to `json_encode`.

Edit: `\b` isn't likely to be the cause. That's the bell character. `\p` however isn't allowed. See http://json.org/ for the spec.

Comment: Yes \p is the issue. Any code snippets to sanitize the json string so that resulting json will adhere to spec ?

Comment: "sanitizing" isn't a thing. There's no way to reliably fix all encoding mishaps after the fact. Fix ***your*** string declaration.

Comment: well the string is coming from a datasource and there are 20,000 of them. So fixing string manually is not an option.

Comment: If the string in fact came "from a datascource" (don't be that vague) as this, then it wouldn't need fixing. The problem is *you* redeclaring it as PHP string here.